# Tracking where variables are used when calling another class

Tags: java

This is a bit out of the box but I have a requirement to track input to methods and track where they are used in another classes.  Is there any good way to do this given the code could be refactored and changed and I want to ensure the mapping maintains it accuracy?

```
// doSomething is under my control
@Endpoint("testEndpoint")
public void doSomething(String name, int age, String surname) {

   String fullName = name + " " + surname;

   // SendRequest is generated code (not under my control)
   SendRequest sr = new SendRequest();
   sr.setFullName(fullName);
   sr.setUserAge(age)
   this.sender.send(sr);

}
```

So they ouput might be

```
testEndpoint
  INPUT <> OUTPUT
  ---------------
  name -> fullName
  age -> userAge
  surname -> fullName
```

I need this information at runtime and before the method is executed.  My current solution is inspired from [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) and uses reflection and a custom annotated transformation class which I can read at runtime to gather the dependencies and pull out this information - in effect turning a type safe language into a type unsafe language.

Just wondering if there is a better solution or some library out there that can do this.

Comment: You can use log4j for this. and use the output file as your output file.

Comment: But this would require the method to be executed, I need this information be fore that time.

Comment: @Azodious Can you elaborate on the log4j solution a little more?

Comment: are you doing some calculation based on this info? if not then you can execute your code two times with same input. first with logger level INFO and second with DEBUG.

Comment: There are calculations but I am not concerned with the values - just the names of the mappings.

Comment: Ok. then i'm thinking that you can put your method code in `if` condition, such as `if(logger.logLevel == Logger.DEBUG)`. so this will be called only if log level is set DEBUG. and have log4j logging for some other log level for the output you want. and execute code two times, first with other log level to get required mapping in file. then change the log level to DEBUG and execute. now method code will execute and you have already got the mapping in required format.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/)?

You could define a point cut that matches the method(s) of which you'd like to capture the arguments and then define an advice that actually captures and stores, tracks, whatever the argument values.

```
public aspect ExampleAspect {

  pointcut doSomething() : call(public void doSomething(String,int,String));

  before(): doSomething(){
    System.out.println("INPUT <> OUTPUT");
    System.out.println("---------------");
    System.out.println("name -> "+ this.JoinPoint.getArgs[0]);
    System.out.println("age -> "+ this.JoinPoint.getArgs[1]);
    System.out.println("surname -> "+ this.JoinPoint.getArgs[2]);
  }

}
```

Comment: I did consider aspects but I need the opposite information.  I don't care about the values, I want the input names matched to the output names.

Comment: In my case I have inputs from a REST API output to a WebServices API.  Trying to track what input affects what output.